# SSRS rotate over when printing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have printing form 100X70 (mm) for pallet sticker in ssrs. How i can rotate form when printing? because sticker size 70x100 (mm). Mb rotate report in Design for 90 degrees , but it's not usability. Sorry for my Eng.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNKRh.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKNfo.jpg)

Comment: It sounds like you just need to change your report layout to landscape orientation.

Comment: When i change landscape the printed form goes to the side and the floor of the empty half sheet with the cropped text is obtained, but the width is normal, if you put the size of the sticker 10 x 10 the shape can not be rotated, if this would be possible it would be perfect.

Comment: Can you mark up a printed report and upload a scan of it? It's a bit hard to fix without a picture.

Comment: image in header

Comment: Can you increase the margin size after the layout is changed to landscape?

Comment: And the hardest to understand how to rotate square printed forms?

Comment: I think you may need to play around with resizing the margins. Is there more than one sticker per page?

Comment: Not yet, but I'll make

Comment: Interestingly enough happened. Made the form 15 to 10 album and everything went well, the point is that the search for dimensions (from where it takes that my form should be 15 to 10) realized that the size it takes from the printer .... there is 4x6 in which is 10 x 15 cm (approximately)